MERN APP works on deployed Render site, but no longer works locally
I came back and revisited an app I was working on a few months back, its currently still working from its deployed site on Render, but when I try to run it locally, I'm encountering this 500 error response in dev tools.
network error
This is my terminal response
  VITE v5.4.0  ready in 125 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:3000/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h + enter to show help
10:45:13 PM [vite] http proxy error: /graphql
AggregateError
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)

My vite config
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      "/graphql": {
        target: "http://localhost:3001",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
  test: {
    environment: "happy-dom",
    globals: true,
  },
});

My server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
// Import the ApolloServer class
const { ApolloServer } = require('@apollo/server');
const { expressMiddleware } = require('@apollo/server/express4');
const { authMiddleware } = require('./utils/auth');

// Import the two parts of a GraphQL schema
const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require('./schemas');
const db = require('./config/connection');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  formatError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  },
});

const app = express();

// Create a new instance of an Apollo server with the GraphQL schema
const startApolloServer = async () => {
  await server.start();

  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(express.json());

  app.use(
    '/graphql',
    expressMiddleware(server, {
      context: authMiddleware,
    })
  );

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/index.html'));
    });
  }

  db.once('open', () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`API server running on port ${PORT}!`);
      console.log(`Use GraphQL at http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`);
    });
  });
};

// Call the async function to start the server
startApolloServer();

My client-side package json
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.11.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "graphql": "^16.9.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "happy-dom": "^14.3.8",
    "vitest": "^2.0.5"
  }
}

My server-side package json
{
  "name": "apollo-mern",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "boilerplate code for MERN application",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "develop": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run watch\" \"cd client && npm run dev\"",
    "install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i",
    "seed": "cd server && npm run seed",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "hero-slider": "^3.2.1"
  }
}

I've spent a few hours looking up suggestions. I've tried the following;
Adding a proxy setting in package json like...
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"

Adjusting my server and PORT settings in my vite config and in the server.js
Updating all of my dependencies.

Have you actually started your Express server and received the console message "API server running on port 3001!"?

FYI proxy in package.json is not something Vite uses

I did get the server up and running with the response of "API server running on port 3001!"   I dunno if this is gives better context, but running the  "npm run start" terminal command brings back an error, while running nodemon in the terminal is whats starting the server properly.

And thank you for confirming about the proxy package.json! I figured it wasn't needed since I've had the app running without issues in the past without it, but I wasn't sure.

"running the "npm run start" terminal command brings back an error"... what error, exactly?

So are you starting the server first (and getting the "API server running..." message) and then starting the front-end with npm run dev? Perhaps try enabling debug logging with npm run dev -- -d

The error message: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Dayme\Bootcamp\projects\bug-box\server\server\server.js'

I do start the server and get that API...response, but in order to run npm run dev, I need to stop that in the terminal and cd into the client-side.

Well there's your problem. Just open another terminal

:O that worked haha. Such a simple fix, I didn't realize the server wasn't working in the background..silly as that may sound. Thank you so much for the help!!

Per advice from Phil in the comments, I realized my issue was not having my server running while accessing the app. I just had to make sure to run the server in one terminal, and then start my app in a new additional terminal.
